# What do I do if I get more than one good answer?

Tags: discussion

Is there anything I can do if I want to check two answer as being good? What's the proper etiquette in this situation? I was thinking to just mark both answer up without a check and let the community decide.

Answer (score 3):

I would choose the better one and vote up both answers.

Comment: What if both are equally good answers? Does marking answered give the person who answered more reputation?

Comment: Yes, marking as accepted gives 15 reputation points to the person which wrote the answer. If they are both equal, then you have to decide.

Comment: No you don't.‍‍

Comment: What if I answer that both were helpful and mark my own. Of course I wouldn't expect any points for that.

Comment: @J.Musser Of course you only have to decide wen you want to accept an answer. It's up to the person which asks the question to leave this open.

Answer (score 3):

Accepting isn't 'marking as best answer', it's 'marking as most helpful to the OP'. If one answer is not notable more helpful than another, and they helped you equally, remember you aren't required to accept one.

In any case, it is always a good idea to wait (I often wait 24-48 hrs) before accepting, because most users will be less likely to add another answer to a thread where one as already been accepted, and you will be more likely to get more feedback before ou click accept.

And of course, vote up any answer that has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to pick the better one and check that. The last thing I would do is leave an answered question appear to be unanswered.

Comment: Questions with upvoted answers but no checked answer don't show up in the unanswered queue/search.